# Serialize a STL containers of arbitrary type (including other containers) C++

Tags: c++, serialization, stl

Let me start off by saying that I can't use boost, as this is supposed to be practice. Or a punishment. Not really sure now.

I have to write a function that looks something like this:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void serialize<T1, T2>(std::map<T1, T2> in, std::vector<uint8_t>* buf);
```

I would then iterate over the map, serializing every pair of elements in each entry. But then, I encounter an issue.

The problem that I have right now, is that T1 may be, say, a std::vector filled with other std::vector's. I have another function that looks similar to the above, and assume that works correctly, like so:

```
template <class T1>
void serialize<T1>(std::vector<T1> in, std::vector<uint8_t>* buf);
```

Which would have the same issues as the function above. Should I just scrap this and work on a different approach? Or is this still workable? Am I just missing something?

Comment: Have you considered deserializing? Given a buffer in input, how will you know what is serialized there?

Comment: that's really neither here nor there, but I was thinking of just having a flag in the buffer where the reading begins... something like 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: It is *here*. Serializing is simple: the compiler is aware of the types you are serializing, no RTTI is necessary (unless you decide to "hide" them and serialize a virtual base class). However, those flags that you planned to sprinkle in?... those are of the RTTI-nature! And as they are **Runtime** type info, templates aren't going to help you as much as you may think. Think seriously what are the particulars of your needs in both ways before taking a decision.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by that. I was originally going to just have a serialize method. And I am also confused by what the italicized here means.

Comment: whoops, forgot enter wasn't a thing. anyway, I was going to have multiple, overloaded serialize methods, so I figured that if I just got the entry then sent it to another serialize method, it would be able to know what type the data was and handle it properly. so something like `code`for (iterator...) { serialize(it->first, buf); serialize(it->second, buf);}`code`

Comment: " And I am also confused by what the italicized here means" It was in relation with your "that's really neither here nor there,". As in, "you may think it's off-topic, but it's not so"

Comment: "I don't quite understand what you mean by that. I was originally going to just have a serialize method." Try a small scale example with serialization in **both** directions and you'll get to understand what the problem is (compile-time polymorphism by templates is useful in serialization, but most of the time useless at de-serialization).

Comment: I think that I may have a bit too much of Java in my head to understand properly... but I think I'm starting to see what you meant. That said, thanks for the help.

Comment: Google "Compile-time polymorphism" (aka "templates and template specialization") - Java has Runtime Type Info build-in, C++ is nazi-er in this respect. In Java, you can have `Map<Object,...>` and have one `ArrayList` as key and another `String` key in the same map. In C++, a `map<T1, ...>` will only accept `T1`-s as the key (also google "object slicing" ... relevant to "But what if I use `T1`-es *and derived* as keys?")

Answer (score 0):

If you have to know whether or not the element is a vector or not, or a vector of vector, etc., using templates is not the proper solution.

You should just make an object that has a union:

```
bool isVector;
union
{
    vector<T> v;
    T t;
}
```

Make the key of your map with such an object. Or use an enum if there are more possibilities.

A template should have the same behavior for whatever type it contains known at compile-time. In your case, the type of objects will only be known at run-time.